# One column in join table unaffected by WHERE clause, My SQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following code:

```
SELECT YEAR(user.reg_date) AS year,
    MONTH(user.reg_date) AS month,
    DATE (
        CASE 
            WHEN DAYOFWEEK(user.reg_date) >= 2
                THEN DATE_SUB(user.reg_date, INTERVAL(DAYOFWEEK(user.reg_date) - 2) DAY)
            ELSE DATE_ADD(user.reg_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
            END
        ) AS week_of,
    count(*) AS signups,
    COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN user.gender = 'M'
                THEN user.user_id
            END) AS males,
    COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN user.gender = 'F'
                THEN user.user_id
            END) AS females,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM unsubscribe
        INNER JOIN user ON user.token = unsubscribe.token
        WHERE DATE (DATETIME) BETWEEN week_of
                AND DATE_ADD(week_of, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
        ) AS unsubscribe
FROM user
INNER JOIN place ON user.place_id = place.place_id
WHERE user.reg_date IS NOT NULL
    AND YEAR(user.reg_date) >= YEAR(CURDATE()) - 2
    AND place.contained_by = '207'
GROUP BY CONCAT (
        YEAR(user.reg_date),
        '/',
        WEEK(user.reg_date)
        )
ORDER BY week_of;
```

My final table result almost works, however the column called unsubscribe in the join table is unaffected/not filtered by the last where statement and I am not sure why.

EDITED:
This is the outcome I am getting. The schema is correct, however all columns are filtered by place_id EXCEPT for unsubscribe. I need unsubscribe to be filtered by place_id as well.

```
|year |month |week_of    |signups |males |females |unsubscribe |
|2015 |1     |2014-12-29 |5       |1     |4       |269         |
```

Comment: You're probably going to need a nested query.

Comment: What is the "last where statement"?

Comment: @JNevill thank you for the edit! Sorry, am new to this!

Comment: @knod, no prob. What logic is it exactly that isn't being applied? It might help if you could share you table schema (cut down to just the relevant fields here), some small sample data, and what your expected output would be. It's not super clear what you are trying to achieve with the code, since obviously the code isn't doing what you need.

Comment: @JNevill thanks - just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to correlate your subquery to the main query in your WHERE clause according to the place_id from the user table. You are filtering on your place table in the main query, and you are already joining in the user table in your subquery, so you can use the `user.place_id` to do this in your WHERE clause.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM unsubscribe INNER JOIN user  
     ON user.token = unsubscribe.token
 WHERE DATE (DATETIME) BETWEEN week_of
     AND DATE_ADD(week_of, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
     AND user.place_id = place.place_id
```

Comment: This made the unsubscribe column all 0 (which I know is not the case).

Comment: Perhaps I've made another assumption about you are trying to do. I think I understand now. I'll write it up here in a second.

Comment: OK I've updated it with another stab. This should give you a count of unsubscribed users within that time range and filter it for the place_id that is filtered in your main query using the correlation in the WHERE statement to the main query's place.place_id.

Comment: that's it! Thank you SO much. I see now that unsubscribe was missing the place_id association.